# What is the probability that of 5 people hired, 2 are from New Jersey?

Tags: probability

A company in New Jersey is hiring $5$ people for a position. Of the applicants, $7$ are from New Jersey, $8$ are from New York, and $5$ are from Pennsylvania. What is the probability that of the $5$ people hired, exactly $two$ are from New Jersey?

I'm not sure how to approach this problem.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your thoughts and efforts (work in progress) in this and future posts. 
You are more likely to receive positive/constructive feedback that way.  
Formatting your post helps too.
Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: **Hint:** 
How many ways to choose 5 people?

Out of all the groups of 5, how many have exactly 2 people from NJ?

Comment: 20C5 = 15,504. I'm not sure how to figure out how many groups have 2 people from New Jersey, and I cant exactly write out 15,000 groups out by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=7$ be the number of applicants from NJ, and $B = 13$ be the number of non NJ applicants. Then the number of ways to choose $2$ persons from NJ is
$$\binom{7}{2}$$
The number of ways to choose the rest (non NJ) is
$$\binom{13}{3}$$
The total you gave is right, so the probability of interest is 
$$\frac{\binom{7}{2}\binom{13}{3}}{\binom{20}{5}} = \frac{1001}{2584} = 0.38738390.$$

Comment: Just wanted to make sure, the reason you did the first (5 over 2) is because 20 - 15 = 5? Because there are 7 total applicants from New Jersey.

Comment: @user314781 Sorry about that, I got the number of NJ and Pennsylvania mixed up. It should be right now.

Comment: @user314781 You can think of this as having a bag of $7$ white balls and $13$ black balls, then drawing 5 balls without replacement. This is situation follows a hypergeometric distribution, if you know what that is.

Comment: Thank you! It makes much more sense to me now!

Comment: @Koalafications No problem, glad to help. Make sure to post your thoughts in future posts. Consider giving respondents a [check mark](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

just apply the hypergeometric distribution:
$$\frac{\bigg(\begin{array}{c}
             7 \\ 2
             \end{array}\bigg)\bigg(\begin{array}{c}
             13 \\ 3
             \end{array}\bigg)}{\bigg(\begin{array}{c}
             20 \\ 5
             \end{array}\bigg)}=\frac{\frac{7!}{2!5!}\frac{13!}{10!3!}}{\frac{20!}{15!5!}}=\frac{\frac{6*7}{2}\frac{11*12*13}{2*3}}{\frac{16*17*18*19*20}{2*3*4*5}}=...$$

Comment: Thank you! That helps me a lot!